# Assigning data from an array, or what?

Tags: javascript

I came across this line and I'm unsure how it does what it does. The data portion is a json object and later on, the "myarray" variable is used to assign new variables to an array.

The "myItems" object is used to iterate through a .map function over the objects in the data object. But I have no idea how this all gets assigned through the code below:

```
var myItems = data || [], myarray;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It declares two global variables `myItems` and `myarray`.  My items is assigned data if data is not undefined, if data is undefined it assigns an empty array to `myItems`.

The `||` operator can be used during assignment due to the truthy or falsey nature of variables in Javascript.

Several values equate to false in Javascript such as an empty string `""` or undefined.  Others such as a String literal != "" (Example "Test") and objects will equate to true.  When used in assignment the section of code proceeding the `||` will not be evaluated if the first expression equates to true.

This [link](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) gives a better description of truthy and falsey.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to write this would be:

```
var myItems;
if (data) {
    myItems = data;
} else {
    myItems = [];
}

var myarray;
```

Answer (score 1):

This line of code does the following:

- it declares `myarray` and `myItems` variables.
- `data || []` means take `data` if evaluates to true (not empty), otherwise take new empty array. This is kind of javascript mnemonic to provide fallback/default values.
- Assigns the result of previous step to `myItems`

So, it's better written as

```
var myarray;
var myItems = data || [];
```

Answer (score -1):

Here, you're defining two variables called `data` and `myarray` (take note of the comma).

The `||` (logical OR operator) is being lightly abused here. The statement

```
var myItems = data || [];
```

Will assign the value of `data` to `myItems` if `data` is **not** falsy. If it *is* falsy, however, `myItems` will be initialised as an empty array with `[]`. Due to lazy evaluation, if `data != false`, the rest of the statement is not executed.